# Combining ids in StartsWith selector and length property

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to look for an ID on a page before running some form validation code. I'd like to add a second ID type to the wrapping if statement.

Current script:

```
if($('[id^="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"]').length){}});
```

How would I incorporate another id in there? I've tried:

```
if($('[id^="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"]','[id^="form_email"]').length{}});
```

This doesn't seem to work though.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('[id^="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"],[id^="form_email"]')
```

As per your current code, You are passing context

```
$('[id^="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"]','[id^="form_email"]')
```

which is equivalent to

```
$('[id^="form_email"]').find('[id^="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Omit the quotes for the multiple selector. You need to use a comma separated way to specify multiple different selector for the same operation. `length` in your case.

```
if($('[id^="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"],[id^="form_email"]').length{}});
```

Comment: Always a quote away

Comment: @okass it happens. Glad to help you.